# Connect Aurora PostgreSQL from AWS Lake Formation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Can I use Aurora PostgreSQL as my source for Blueprint in AWS Lake Formation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can connect to a JDBC datasource.

See: [Tutorial: Creating a Data Lake from a JDBC Source in Lake Formation - AWS Lake Formation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/getting-started-tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi John, it has allowed the connection for me but crawler has failed with my Aurora PostGreSQL while triggering the workflow. As per the console they have not mentioned Aurora hence I got confused